# How create several versions of program file?

Tags: c#

I'm greenhorn,
I have a project with program.cs file and 3 class files. And I want to create and test another version of file program.cs (named program2.cs) with same classes as firstone (I use VS). What is best way to create second version of program?

I try to add a new file in Solution explorer and copy there code from original program.cs file but there are errors with classes.

Comment: It sounds like you probably want multiple projects: a class library with the common classes, then multiple application projects (e.g. console applications) which refer to the library.

Comment: put your class inside another namespace

Comment: @AlexeyObukhov Could you give me more details please

Comment: @PetrKopecký added answer with details

Comment: It seems that something as simple as copying the solution folder (and it's contents), may  work for you. Open Windows File Explorer, right-click the solution folder, ctrl-V to paste. Rename as desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create classes with the same name (in the same or different files), you just need to put them in different namespaces

```
using System;

namespace TestNamespace1
{
    public class SomeClass
    {
        public static void SomeFunc()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("TestNamespace1");
        }
    }
}

//class names do not conflict with each other
namespace TestNamespace2
{
    public class SomeClass
    {
        public static void SomeFunc()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("TestNamespace2");
        }
    }
}

//no matter what namespace, the entry point is determined by the name of the method
namespace ConsoleApp6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestNamespace1.SomeClass.SomeFunc(); //TestNamespace1
            TestNamespace2.SomeClass.SomeFunc(); //TestNamespace2
        }
    }
}
```